# FInding no of child nodes in XML root element using libxml2

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

Given an XML

```
<root>
<node1></node1>
<node1></node1>
<node1></node1>
<node1></node1>
<node1></node1>
</root>
```

I want to find the number of child having tag name node1 using libxml2

```
xmlNode  *root = NULL;
root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
```

I dont want to iterate each child node and count the number of nodes until NULL

I want to know is thier any function available which can be applied to root to find the number of childnodes having nametag node1.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the XPath API

http://www.xmlsoft.org/tutorial/ar01s05.html

To evaluate the XPath `count(/root/node1)`